# How to get all the functionality of a type without exposing it to the client?

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I just got in trouble from a teacher and I'm a little confused.

I have data that is stored in a `VectorWithTops` class like this

```
public class VectorWithTops<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, int> TopsWithIndices = 
       new Dictionary<T, int>();
    private readonly Vector<double> _data;

    public VectorWithTops(
       List<T> topHeaders,
       Vector<double> data)
       {
           // set TopsWithIndices to be topHeaders and index in vector
           // ...

           _data = data
       }

    // method to get value in vector at certain topHeader index
    // ...
}
```

The whole purpose of this class is to be able to access a vector index by it's respective header of type `T`. The vector itself is not exposed to the client however.

Now I have a different class in which I am using a VectorWithTops, and in order to perform a bunch of operations on my vector I decided to expose `_data` in a public method, then directly operate on the matrix. I figured this was fine because `_data` is private readonly so it's not going to be able to be changed anyways.

My teacher sort of lost his mind at this, and told me what I should have done is add the operators to my `VectorWithTops` class for instance

```
static Vector<double> operator *(VectorWithTops<T> leftSide, Vector<double> rightSide)
{
    return leftSide._data*rightSide;
}
```

Then I can use this static method without exposing the actual vector to the client. **My question is then** how is this encapsulation going to work if I require a *great deal* of the operator methods for my vector, or a matrix even? Would I have to rewrite all of these static methods in my own class so that the data is ensured to be operated on inside my class? I understand my teacher's complaint about the vector in my case being exposed, but how am I supposed to freely operate on my vector inside `VectorWithTops` then?

Comment: On the real world you would use the vector, but you're on a classroom, so you just must do whatever your teacher says, even if it's just an abomination...

Comment: @Gusman Why is it an abomination though, his suggestion? It seems to me there is some importance maybe for not exposing the vector itself?

Comment: The sentence was just general, not strictly about this code. But, you're talking about matrices, vectors, and so on, so this code smells like a 3d program of some sort, which is a very computational-intensive task, and encapsulating all the operators are going to slow down things, so *maybe* is an abomination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `Vector<T>` is an immutable type which isn't even passed by reference.  Provided that your field definition remains readonly, there's no danger in exposing it.  It cannot be changed by another object without using reflection hacks.

You *could* make the argument that the `Vector<T>` is an implementation-specific detail that might change in a future, and that consumers of your `VectorsWithTops<T>` class should not rely on that field remaining the same.  But unless you're a masochist I wouldn't go any further than just adding a public getter/property for the `Vector<T>`.  If at some point you need to change your private field to another data structure, the public property could be modified at that time to perform a conversion.

On the other hand, sometimes you just gotta do what the teacher wants to pass the class...